# keyframe animation is not working on the right-margin but works perfect on the left-margin

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i'm trying to perform an animation on the id="hello" element , the animation doesn't work on the right margin , but works perfectly on the left margin , any ideas please?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #hola {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: red;
            animation-name: hola;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
        #hello {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: red;
            animation-name: hello;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;}
        @keyframes hola {
            from {
           `    margin-left: -250px;
            }

            to {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }}
        @keyframes hello {
            from {
                margin-right: 10px;}
            to {
                margin-right: 1000px;}}
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>My tranforming element</h1>
        <div id="hola"><p>Hola</p></div>
        <div id="hello"><p>Hello</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're adding `margin-right` on the right side of the box, and since the box is aligned to the left, it doesn't push the box to the side.

And `margin-left` works because the boxes are aligned to the left, so adding a negative value will pull them out of view.

The `margin-right` animation would work if the box was aligned to the right.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #hola {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: red;
            animation-name: hola;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            
        #hello {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: red;
            animation-name: hello;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            
            /* Second box is aligned to the right */
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            }
        @keyframes hola {
            from {
                margin-left: -250px;
            }

            to {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }}
        @keyframes hello {
            from {
                margin-right: -250px;}
            to {
                margin-right: 10px;}}
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>My tranforming element</h1>
        <div id="hola"><p>Hola</p></div>
        <div id="hello"><p>Hello</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im not sure what kind of animation are you trying to accomplish tho.

Comment: oh so that's it , thanks man. for the animation I wanna achieve a simple translate from right to left and left to right when I scroll over these elements

Answer (score 0):

That is because the page direction is LTR (Left To Right), and even if the page direction changed to RTL (Right To Left) Then: "margin-left" wont work anymore but "margin-right" will work!!

The easiest solution is to change the "**margin-right**" to "**margin-left**", and reverse the direction by adding a minus (**-**) so the movement will be done in the reversed direction of "**left**" which is "**right**".

Final code of the "**hello**" Animation:

```
@keyframes hello {
    from {
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -1000px;
    }
}
```

> Also I have noticed that you wrote > ` < before "margin-left" on the from section of "hola" animation don't forget to remove it.

Comment: oh so that's it , thank you man